# asp.net web service on local server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I create a new web service in VS and I create a function that return a value

This the code of my function

```
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
 Public Class Service
 Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function CalculerTaxe() As String
    Dim tps As Double = 0.095
    Dim tvq As Double = 0.05
    Dim PrixHors As Double
    Dim PrixFinal As Double = PrixHors * tps * tvq
    Return PrixFinal.ToString()
End Function
```

End Class

So I don't change the namespace because I don't know what write for a virtual server?...

What I have to do to make my service work in a another web site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I have to do to make my service work in a another web site?

Nothing; you just need to expose your web service on a public URL. Other websites should be able to code against your web service transparently.

Comment: I Want to use it in another "Virtual site web" on local Host This is a project...Its not publish now...

Comment: @FrankSharp create the other virtual web site in another project and click on "Add Service Reference" then follow the wizard. It will show you the list of web services hosted on your local machine

Answer (score 1):

First you need to host your web service on iis (same way you do for website).

Then you can call your webservice from other applications or websites.

A simple webservice call might look like this..  http://hostname/sample.ashx?tps=222&tvq=655